# How to get channels and groups data from my Telegram account?(Python)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

How can I get last posts and messages from all channel and groups in my Telegram account using "telethon".

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 3):

At first you should get your "api_id" and "api_hash" from [Telegram API](https://my.telegram.org/auth).
then you should use following code to connect to your Telegram account.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
# Create the client and connect
client = TelegramClient(you_username, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
print("Client Created")
# Ensure you're authorized
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(your_phone)
    try:
        client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    except SessionPasswordNeededError:
        client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))
```

In the next step we define a `def` to get last message of an entity (like channel or group):

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
def get_entity_data(entity_id, limit):
    entity = client.get_entity(entity_id)
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    # y = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
                   peer=entity,
                   limit=limit,
                   offset_date=None,
                   offset_id=0,
                   max_id=0,
                   min_id=0,
                   add_offset=0,
                   hash=0))

     messages = []
     for message in posts.messages:
          messages.append(message.message)
     return messages
```

This `def` gets id of a channel or group and limit on number of messages that we want to get from any channels and groups and returns the messages.

Then you should get all groups and channels using this code:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=None,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=100,
             hash=0)) 
 entities = result.chats
```

And in last step you should iterate on entities and get last messages(for example 10 in following code)

```
for entity in entities:
    title = entity.title
    messages = get_entity_data(entity.id, 10)
    print(title + ' :')
    print(messages)
    print('#######')
```