# how to get posts in a telegram megagroup

Tags: python, telegram, posts, telethon

I am trying to get the post's text of a megagroup in Telegram using Telethon. I could get the messages from chats however megagroup's posts cannot be retrieved using the same method ([How to get channels and groups data from my Telegram account?(Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645421/how-to-get-channels-and-groups-data-from-my-telegram-accountpython)). Are megagroups open to fetch their posts by being a simple user using telethon?

Code:

```
def get_entity_data(entity_id, limit):
    entity = client.get_entity(entity_id)
    posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(peer=entity, limit=limit, offset_date=None, offset_id=0, max_id=0, min_id=0, add_offset=0, hash=0))
    messages = []
    for message in posts.messages:
         messages.append(message.message)
    return messages

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(offset_date=None, offset_id=0, offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(), limit=100, hash=0)) entities = result.chats entities.reverse()

for entity in entities:
    title = entity.title
    messages = get_entity_data(entity.id, 10)
    print(title + ' :')
    print(messages)
    print('#######')
```

and the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./search_message3.py", line 61, in <module>
    messages = get_entity_data(entity.id, 10)
  File "./search_message3.py", line 48, in get_entity_data
    entity = client.get_entity(entity_id)
  File "/home/carlos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/home/carlos/.miniconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/carlos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 316, in get_entity
    chats = (await self(
  File "/home/carlos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "/home/carlos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 84, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type and that the value is valid (for instance, bots cannot start conversations) (caused by GetChatsRequest)
```

Carlos

Comment: Megagroups can be treated as [channels](https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/chats-and-channels.html#joining-a-chat-or-channel). What is your code and why doesn't it work?

Comment: I put the code above and the error message. It works well for chats but not for retrieven posts in megagroups

Comment: I've just realize it might be a limitation on the stable telethon version ("Client doesn't get content from a channel with resctricted saving content enabled"). It seems I was dealing with a megagroup with this restriction enabled